# Convert a Pandas dataframe cell with strings to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, row

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
Index   Type        Value
0       INT         0
1       INT         100
2       ENUM        "val1","val2","val3"
3       HEX         0x0
4       ENUM        "val1","val2"
5       ENUM        1,4,3,8
```

Here's the sample output I want from a **Value row** with **ENUM type**:

```
List = ["val1","val2","val3"]
```

So that when I call `List[0]` the output is `val1`

Here's what I tried:

1. Creating an empty list and appending the Value cell to the list.

```
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
     if(row['Type']=='ENUM'):
        List = []
        List.append(row['Value']
        doSomething()
        List.clear() # I need to clear the list for every iteration
```

In this case the length of the list is 1, and the output looks like this

```
List = ['"val1","val2","val3"']
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert this strings as list:

```
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
     if(row['Type']=='ENUM'):
        List = row['Value'].replace('"', '').split(',')
        print(List)
```

Output:

```
['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
['val1', 'val2']
['1', '4', '3', '8']
```

Permanent change in dataframe:

```
m = dataframe['Type'] == 'ENUM'
dataframe.loc[m, 'Value'] = (dataframe.loc[m, 'Value']
                                      .str.replace('"', '')
                                      .str.split(','))
print(dataframe)

# Output
   Type               Value
0   INT                   0
1   INT                 100
2  ENUM  [val1, val2, val3]
3   HEX                 0x0
4  ENUM        [val1, val2]
5  ENUM        [1, 4, 3, 8]
```

Now, you have real list in `Value` column.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df['Value'].str.split(',')
```

Output:

```
0                       [0]
1                     [100]
2    [val1, "val2", "val3"]
3                     [0x0]
4            [val1, "val2"]
5              [1, 4, 3, 8]
Name: Value, dtype: object
```